# Please vote on tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, announcement

Please remember to [vote on tag synonyms](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested) if you are an experienced user.

Currently we have a [suggestion](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/1236) to synonomize [micronutrients](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micronutrients) with [vitamins-and-minerals](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamins-and-minerals) that has been [awaiting votes](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/vitamins-and-minerals/synonyms) for more than a year. If you're new like me, you might not be aware that synonyms are approved when they receive sufficient votes from people with experience on the tag. Surprisingly there is no review queue for suggested tag synonyms.

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

*bump*

Comment: I'm bumping this, hoping to get attention of the site's moderators. These [suggested synonyms](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) have been sitting in queue for over a year.

Comment: Never mind, I just retagged the questions myself because I can't create synonyms.